# computing weight from distance metric

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I have a distance between two points in meters. I want to convert this distance into weight such that as distance increases the weight decreases.

What are some good weighting function that can achieve is, that is as distance gets too large the weight to decrease sharply.

Some commonly used [kernel functions are here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)#Kernel_functions_in_common_use) but I am confused it this shall be ok.

Comment: Why don't you think the linked functions would be ok?

Comment: No I am not saying it is not ok but I was wondering if there are any other perhaps better once. I am using Epanechnikov

Answer (score 1):

I think that they are almost ok but it depends on what do you exactly need.

I see two potential problems among the kernel functions you mentioned (they arise because kernel functions are made for density estimation but you want something little bit different).

1) All of these functions are symetrical around $0$ but you have distances that are always non-negative.

2) Most of these functions are non-zero only in interval $[-1;1]$. If most of your distances are greater than 1 meter, this problem is quite serious.

Because of the second problem, I recommend you to use Gaussian, Logistic or Silverman kernel. If you also wanted to get rid of the first problem, you can for example use a pdf of exponential distribution which is $\lambda \cdot e^{-\lambda x}$, where $x \geq 0$ is the distance and $\lambda > 0$ is a parameter of your choice.

But as I said, the optimal solution depends only on your needs.